# Converting Integer to Binary return wrong values

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, integer

I created a Numeric Translator where I need to convert Integer to Binary. When I tried to convert Integer `12`. It gives me a value `0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0` instead of `0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0`.

Code:

```
number = int(input("Enter a integer between 255 and 0: "))
    if (number > 255) or (number < 0):
        print("Please input less than 255!!!")
    else:
        a = False

        for myCounter in range (8): 

            if (number % 2 == 1):#if remainder is equal to 1
                myResult = ' 1 ' + myResult#add '1' character to the string

            else: 
                (number % 2 == 0)#if input has no remainder
                myResult = ' 0 ' + myResult#add '0' character to the string

            number = number / 2

        print("Binary equivalent is: %s" %myResult)
```

[image: Screenshot]

How can I round off the `0.5` to `1` using ROUND_HALF_UP? Output below.

[image: Output]

Any help would appreciated thanks!

Comment: `math.ceil(0.5)` -> `1.0` is that what you want? (or just add 0.5 and truncate: `int(n+0.5)`)

Comment: try `number = number //2`

Comment: Please do not use parentheses inside `if`

Comment: @RicardoCruz no it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine in Python 2.7. For [Python 3.x](http://ideone.com/haiVpb) try replacing `number = number/2` to `number=number//2`

```
number = 12
a = False
myResult  = ''
for myCounter in range (8): 

    if (number % 2 == 1):#if remainder is equal to 1
        myResult = ' 1 ' + myResult#add '1' character to the string

    else: 
        (number % 2 == 0)#if input has no remainder
        myResult = ' 0 ' + myResult#add '0' character to the string

    number = number // 2

print("Binary equivalent is: %s" %myResult)
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me! Why should I use `Floor Division` instead of `Division Symbol`?

Comment: @MiaLegaspi yep :)

Comment: For those who are more inclined to use bitwise operations, `myResult = str(number & 1) + myResult; number >>= 1` would do the same.